# How to check one specific result in MYSQL join from duplicate rows

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to check specific record from join of another table using id but the other table have multiple records with the same id I want to choose the records where there is no everyone in the column.

My SQL is:

```
SELECT b.*
     , a.* 
  FROM engine4_blog_blogs b
  LEFT 
  JOIN engine4_authorization_allow a
    ON a.resource_id = b.blog_id 
 WHERE a.resource_type = 'blog'
   AND a.role NOT IN ('everyone')
   AND a.action = 'view'
   AND b.draft = 0
   AND b.search = 1
 ORDER 
    BY b.creation_date DESC
```

I only want to select record not having everyone and select only one row not duplicates.

```
blog 2 view everyone            0 1 NULL
blog 2 view owner_member        0 1 NULL
blog 2 view owner_member_member 0 1 NULL
blog 2 view owner_network       0 1 NULL
blog 2 view registered          0 1 NULL
```

Thanks,

Comment: You know that renders as an INNER JOIN, right?

Comment: yes but I want to get only one record not the multiple records from my query nit containing the everyone. Now it shows me duplicate rows for one record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to choose rows that don't have "everyone", you need to move all conditions on the second table to the `on` clause:

```
SELECT b.*, a.* 
FROM engine4_blog_blogs b LEFT JOIN
     engine4_authorization_allow a
     ON a.resource_id = b.blog_id AND
        a.resource_type = 'blog' AND
        a.role IN ('everyone') AND
        a.action = 'view'
WHERE b.draft = 0 AND b.search = 1 AND a.resource_id IS NULL
ORDER BY b.creation_date DESC ;
```

If you put conditions in the `WHERE` clause, it filters out all non-matching rows, turning the `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Great! Thanks works like a charm! I don't know why people voting my question down?

Answer (score 3):

you can use distinct command to avoid duplicate record.

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.*
     , a.* 
  FROM engine4_blog_blogs b
  LEFT 
  JOIN engine4_authorization_allow a
    ON a.resource_id = b.blog_id 
 WHERE a.resource_type = 'blog'
   AND a.role NOT IN ('everyone')
   AND a.action = 'view'
   AND b.draft = 0
   AND b.search = 1
 ORDER 
    BY b.creation_date DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.*, a.* 
  FROM engine4_blog_blogs b
  LEFT 
  JOIN engine4_authorization_allow a
  ON a.resource_id = b.blog_id 
  WHERE  a.resource_type = 'blog'
  AND a.action = 'view'
  AND a.role NOT IN ('everyone')
  AND b.draft = 0
  AND b.search = 1
  AND a.resource_id IS NULL
  ORDER BY b.creation_date DESC
```